# Export multiple dataframes to multiple workbooks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

simple question:

I want to export a list of dataframes in to multiple workbooks, one for each df using (df1,df2,df3) as a name but when I try to loop cant get it right, I'm quite new in python.

That's my code

```
import pandas as pd
data_male = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]

data_female = [['Angelina',15],['Marta',14],['Anne',20]] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_male,columns=['Name','Age'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_female,columns=['Name','Age'])

export = [df1,df2]


for i in export:
    i.to_excel( i +'.xlsx')
```

Expected result: 2 independent excel workbooks, one called df1.xlsx with male data and another called df2.xlsx with female data

thanks a lot.

Comment: `for i,d in enumerate(export): d.to_excel(f'{i}.xlsx')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
export = [df1,df2]


for id,i in enumerate(export):
    i.to_excel( 'df'+str(id+1) +'.xlsx')
```

Update

```
d=dict(zip(['df1','df2'], export))

for id,i in d.items():
    i.to_excel( id +'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Ty Yoben it worked!!

Just for future proof, in case of my df list was not in sequence, or even have 'df" as a name, like export = [Sales,Taxes], how do i replicate this? 
to have sales.xlsx and taxes.xlsx

Comment: @AdrianoRibeiro then you need create the dict before that .